# Sencha touch 2 ajax callback function scope

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback, scope, sencha-touch-2

I'm having trouble with the program scope when calling `Ext.Ajax.request`. I need to be able to access the surrounding `Ext.data.Model` instance from the ajax callback function. What is the proper way to achieve this?
I define data model in sencha touch 2 like this:

```
Ext.define('AlbumsData', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
requires: [
    'Ext.Ajax'
],
config: {
    fields: [
        {name: 'someData',  type: 'string'}
    ]
},
getData: function(){
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url : '/somedata.json',
        callback: function(options, success, response) {
            //I want to access the surrounding model instance here and "this" certainly doesn't return the instance of the "Ext.data.Model" in which this getData() method is.
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `scope` option:

```
getData: function(){
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url : '/somedata.json',
        callback: function(options, success, response) {
            //I want to access the surrounding model instance here and "this" certainly doesn't return the instance of the "Ext.data.Model" in which this getData() method is.
        },
        scope: this
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I can just use `this` to access the surrounding instances environment.

Answer (score 1):

Save your `this` in a variable before entering the Ext.AJAX context :

```
getData: function(){
    var scope = this;
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url : '/somedata.json',
        callback: function(options, success, response) {
            scope.get('someData'); //you can now use scope here
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I have tried this and it won't work. `scope: this` is the right way to go in this situation.